# problems running hand_detector on PR2

Tags: ros, openni-kinect, hand-interaction, skeletal-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone gotten hand_detector.launch (the MIT hand detection Kinect library) to run on a PR2 robot?

I've worked through some minor problems with our PR2 running Diamonback:

1. The solution from this post: http://answers.ros.org/question/688/skeletal_tracker-crashes helps solve one problem.
2. The file main.cpp inside of skeletal_tracker (which must be run with this package) has a bunch of calls to OpenGL/GLUT code. You can't run it locally on the PR2 (no monitor), and I've found you can't pipe it over ssh -X for some technical reasons with GLUT (at least that's what I've been able to gather through google). I fixed this situation by modifying main.cpp as follows:

//glInit(&argc, argv);

//glutMainLoop();

ros::spin();

As you can see I just replaced the OpenGL callbacks with a ros::spin. I'm not really sure what the graphical window in this package is for. I'm guessing it's important.

SO ...
Now I can run the code on our PR2 robot without it crashing/complaining, but no messages ever get published to the topics /hands/ /hand0_fullcloud /hand1_fullcloud. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10051/problems-running-hand_detector-on-pr2/) by [JoeRomano](https://answers.ros.org/users/34/joeromano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

It has been almost 4 months since this question was posted. Recently I had the same problem as the one that Joe reports in his question. I don't own a PR2 (yet! ;P) but I was having trouble executing MIT Kinect Demo's hand_detector in a no-monitor environment. So, I would like to share the solution just in case anybody else has the same problem.

As Joe said, the file main.cpp inside skeletal_tracker has a bunch of calls to OpenGL/GLUT code. The problem is that if you do this:

```
//glInit(&argc, argv);
//glutMainLoop();
ros::spin();
```

Then the function *glutDisplay* will never be called. And inside that function is where they get all the data from kinect, process it and publish the skeleton topics.

So the solution could be: create a new function to do the same as *glutDisplay* but without all the GUI stuff. The new function would look like this:

```
void publishSkeletons(void)
{
  xn::SceneMetaData sceneMD;
  xn::DepthMetaData depthMD;
  g_DepthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);

  //Read next available data
  g_Context.WaitAndUpdateAll();
  ros::Time tstamp = ros::Time::now();

  //Process the data
  g_DepthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);
  g_UserGenerator.GetUserPixels(0, sceneMD);
  std::vector<mapping_msgs::PolygonalMap> pmaps;
  body_msgs::Skeletons skels;
  getSkels(pmaps,skels);
  ROS_DEBUG("skels size %d \n",pmaps.size());
  if(pmaps.size()){

    skels.header.stamp=tstamp;
    skels.header.seq = depthMD.FrameID();
    skels.header.frame_id="/openni_depth_optical_frame";
    skel_pub.publish(skels);
    pmaps.front().header.stamp=tstamp;
    pmaps.front().header.seq = depthMD.FrameID();
    pmaps.front().header.frame_id="/openni_depth_optical_frame";
    pmap_pub.publish(pmaps[0]);
  }
}
```

And then change the unwanted calls to OpenGL/GLUT stuff

```
glInit(&argc, argv);
glutMainLoop();
```

for this other calls:

```
ros::Rate loop_rate(30);

while (ros::ok())
{
  
  publishSkeletons();
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();
 
}
```

It works perfectly for me, I hope somebody else finds it useful.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0